# Filter globally using yii2 dropdown list

Tags: yii2, dropdown, yii2-basic-app

I have my drop down list which displays the data from the model, but when I select them it doesn't filter the data accordingly.

```
  <?php  $items = ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Facility::find()->all(),'facility_id' ,'facility_country');?>

   <?= $form->field($model, 'facility_country')->dropDownList($items)->label(false); ?>
```

The above mentioned is the drop-down list in the search form.In the filterSearch model I have used my query like the below mentioned code.

```
  $query->orFilterWhere(['like', 'facility_name', $this->facility_name])
        ->orFilterWhere(['like', 'facility_country', $this->facility_country]);
```

Can I know what the issue is? Thank you!!

Comment: Can you please explain it little better.

Comment: share your rules function of model

Comment: you have passed `facility_id` as value in dropdown and  looking for `facility_country` in search model there is no match. or it's a FK. if not then arrayhelper should be `ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Facility::find()->all(),'facility_country' ,'facility_country');`

Comment: I have changed it to as you have explained it.. but it is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was really simple.. The issue was it was not submitting the form which was just doing nothing.
I was not just submitting the form just added onchange event as the code below.

```
<?php  $items = ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Facility::find()->all(),'facility_country' ,'facility_country');?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'facility_country')->dropDownList($items,['class'=> 'col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-7 pull-left', 'style'=> 'height:34px;','onchange' => 'this.form.submit()'])->label(false);?>
```

Thanks guys for your help..

Answer (score 1):

The value of your `$items` variable are coming from your `\app\models\Facility` class, in an array with the following format:

```
[
    'facility_id' => 'facility_country',
    ...
]
```

When you use this array with [dropDownList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#dropDownList()-detail), you are saying you are sending the key 'facility_id' to your form.

So, in your search model, you need to search by id, something like:

```
->orFilterWhere(['like', 'facility_id', $this->facility_country]);
```

OR you could also do your search by name (I guess that's what you want):

```
$items = ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Facility::find()->all(),'facility_country' ,'facility_country');
```

Comment: I notice that it is just validating the dropdownlist when I inspect the element. I don't understand what is the issue..